# Call specific value from one dataset to another dataset

Tags: excel

I want to create an excel formula in dataset 1 under value that follows the following criteria:

1. Checks if the group matches between both datasets (1 and 2)
2. Checks if the depth in dataset 2 is within the range in dataset 1 given they are in the same group

If everything matches, it should show the value in dataset 2 and input into dataset 1, else should show "Not Found".

This is the formula I have used:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$16:$A$21=A3)*($B$16:$B$21>=B3)*($B$16:$B$21<=C3))>0, INDEX($C$16:$C$21, MATCH(A3, $A$16:$A$21, 0), 1), "Not Found")
```

However, it only shows the value when it result of the first occurrence as show  in the snip

[image]

Comment: Try using `=MATCH(1, (A3=$A$16:$A$21)*(B3=$B$16:$B$21),1)` for the Match portion of your formula

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thank you for your suggestion however it seems to only return a value of 5 when I input it into the spreadsheet.

Comment: Your suggestion provided more ideas to me, now I have figured it out by using `MATCH(1,(A3=$A$16:$A$21)*(B3<=$B$16:$B$21)*(C3>=$B$16:$B$21),0)`.